# HTTPS POST to access catalog with python requests

Tags: python, post, python-requests

We have found a problem with the HTTPS FORM to access the [JPL spectroscopic
catalog](https://spec.jpl.nasa.gov/ftp/pub/catalog/catform.html) using
the python `requests` library. The HTTPS form returns the same response for all queries:
`Zero lines were found for your search criteria.`

```
  r = requests.post('https://spec.jpl.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/catform',
data={'Mol' :'18003+H2O', 'MinNu':"500", 'MaxNu':"600",
         'MaxLines': '2000', 'UnitNu':'GHz', 'StrLim': "-500"})
  print(r.text)
  Out: 'Zero lines were found for your search criteria.\n'
  print(r.status_code)
  Out: 200
```

However querying the form 
https://spec.jpl.nasa.gov/ftp/pub/catalog/catform.html
using a browser (Firefox 60.0.1)
with the request shown below (redirected to the request URL https://spec.jpl.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/catform):

```
POST /cgi-bin/catform HTTP/1.1
Host: spec.jpl.nasa.gov
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Length: 70
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Connection: keep-alive

MinNu=500
MaxNu=600
MaxLines=2000
UnitNu=GHz
StrLim=-500
Mol=18003+H2O
```

gives the following response:

```
  18003  H2O          
  503568.5200  0.0200 -4.9916 3 1394.8142 51 -180031404 8 6 3 0     7 7 0 0     
  504482.6900  0.0500 -5.4671 3 1394.8142 17 -180031404 8 6 2 0     7 7 1 0     
  525890.1638  0.8432-12.2048 3 5035.1266117  18003140419 514 0    18 811 0     
  530342.8600  0.2000 -7.1006 3 2533.7932 87 -18003140414 312 0    13 4 9 0     
  534240.4544  0.3469-11.2954 3 4409.3446 37  18003140418 414 0    17 711 0     
  556935.9877  0.0003 -0.8189 3   23.7944  9 -180031404 1 1 0 0     1 0 1 0     
  557985.4794  0.6432-11.6213 3 4833.2084117  18003140419 415 0    18 712 0     
  558017.0036 12.4193-18.1025 3 7729.4622 49  18003140424 618 0    25 521 0     
  571913.6860  0.1000 -6.9705 3 2414.7235 75 -18003140412 6 7 0    13 310 0     
  591693.4339  0.2120 -8.6820 3 3244.6008 87  18003140414 7 8 0    15 411 0     
  593113.7249  7.4502-18.5975 3 7924.4438 49  18003140424 717 0    231014 0     
  593227.8163  0.4197-10.8822 3 4201.2514 35  18003140417 612 0    18 315 0     
  596308.5878  4.5348-15.8345 3 6687.8251 47  18003140423 519 0    22 616 0
```

Sending the same headers in the `requests` POST call does not help either.

```
headers = {
'Host': 'spec.jpl.nasa.gov',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

data = {
'MaxLines': '2000',
'MaxNu': '600',
'MinNu': '500',
'Mol': '18003+H2O',
'StrLim': '-500',
'UnitNu': 'GHz',
}

r = requests.post('https://spec.jpl.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/catform', headers=headers,
          data=data)

print(r.text)

Out: 'Zero lines were found for your search criteria.\n'
```

There is a redirection from the HTTP version of the form to the HTTPS version
but it seems that this is not causing the problem. Any idea why the code is not
providing the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the data parameters have to be provided in the same order as in the web form of the JPL catalog because the frequency units need to be converted after the code accepts the input for UnitNu. Thus, the data has to be provided as a list of tuples or `OrderedDict` using the same order as in the web form.  This is the script that posts ordered parameters.

```
import requests

data = [('MinNu', '500'),
       ('MaxNu', '1000'),
       ('MaxLines', '2000'),
       ('UnitNu', 'GHz'),
       ('StrLim', '-500'),
       ('Mol', '18003+H2O'),
      ]

r = requests.post('https://spec.jpl.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/catform',
                 data=data)

print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the site, the form post uses HTTP not HTTPS.  It appears their website doesn't respond correctly if you post using HTTPS.

This should work:

```
import requests

data = {
    'MaxLines': '2000',
    'MaxNu': '600',
    'MinNu': '500',
    'Mol': '18003+H2O',
    'StrLim': '-500',
    'UnitNu': 'GHz',
}

r = requests.post('http://spec.jpl.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/catform', data=data)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text.split('\n')[:10])


Out: ['<OPTION>1001  H-atom        ',
 '<OPTION>2001  D-atom        ',
 '<OPTION>3001  HD            ',
 '<OPTION>4001  H2D+          ',
 '<OPTION>7001  Li-6-H        ',
 '<OPTION>8001  LiH           ',
 '<OPTION>8002  Li-6-D        ',
 '<OPTION>9001  LiD           ',
 '<OPTION>12001  C-atom        ',
 '<OPTION>13001  C-13-atom     ']
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) says that if you pass a dictionary it will be encoded automatically.

Comment: Yes, exactly.. python-requests IS urlencoding the dictionary.. But your browser is NOT.  and It appears the web server expects it in the format firefox is posting in.

Comment: That seems unlikely, since that's not how any browser encodes form parameters. I don't think he's showing the raw POST data, he's showing FF's formatted version.

Comment: Browsers only have two ways of sending form parameters (unless the application uses Javascript to format the parameters itself): application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data.

Comment: I just tried the form myself, it sends url-encoded parameters.

Comment: You're correct, i was mistaken.  I added another answer with a working example.

Comment: You should just edit the answer, not post a new answer.

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't work either. The HTTP form is redirected to HTTPS but it only returns a list of input molecules: `print(r.history[0].text)`
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://spec.jpl.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/catform">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>`

Comment: The firefox request URL shown by the web developer tool is https://spec.jpl.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/catform

Comment: If you view source on the page the form action is indeed http not https.  Using chrome developer tools and setting preserve log I see a 307 redirect returned via HTTP.  Honestly I didn't look at the protocol of the responses after that.  I am familiar with Firefox dev tools consolidating multiple requests that include redirects and only showing the last response received.

Comment: Right, I don't know why they have that. However HTTP traffic gets redirected to HTTPS.